# Error in nearbySelectorConfig for Local Search

Tags: optaplanner

I got this error trying to implement NearbySelector in Local Search.
The Local Search  configuration. I tried with both random and original selection orders:

```
                    <changeMoveSelector>
                        <entitySelector id="entitySelector1"/>
                        <selectionOrder>ORIGINAL</selectionOrder>
                        <valueSelector>
                            <nearbySelection>
                                <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector1"/>
                                <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>NearbyGrainMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
                                <parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>40</parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>
                            </nearbySelection>
                        </valueSelector>
                    </changeMoveSelector>
```

Error:

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The nearbySelectorConfig (NearbySelectionConfig()) with randomSelection (false) has distribution parameters.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.common.nearby.NearbySelectionConfig.buildNearbyRandom(NearbySelectionConfig.java:226)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.common.nearby.NearbySelectionConfig.applyNearbyValueSelector(NearbySelectionConfig.java:205)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.value.ValueSelectorConfig.buildValueSelector(ValueSelectorConfig.java:293)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelectorConfig.buildBaseMoveSelector(ChangeMoveSelectorConfig.java:84)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:252)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:241)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelectorConfig.buildBaseMoveSelector(UnionMoveSelectorConfig.java:77)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:252)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildMoveSelector(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:289)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildDecider(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:155)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildPhase(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:141)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildPhase(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:54)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildPhaseList(SolverConfig.java:446)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:349)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
    at App.main(App.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```

Does anyone understand what is happening?
````

Answer (score 1):

The nearby selection requires a `RANDOM` selection order, while your configuration of the `ChangeMoveSelector` specifies `<selectionOrder>ORIGINAL</selectionOrder>`.

Would you try changing it to: `<selectionOrder>RANDOM</selectionOrder>` ?